# Only dates from current week

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I use the following Query to display the entries in my tables where the date is located in the current week. I need to change it to only show from current date to end of the week, not the hole week.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 
SELECT distinct Initials
FROM Scheme
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, Dato, 105) >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
AND convert(datetime, Dato, 105) <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
AND RoomId = ? AND Initials IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please specify dbms. (Many dbms products do not follow the ANSI SQL specification when it comes to date/time handling.)

Comment: You need to clarify your meaning of a week... does a week start on a Sunday, Monday, etc?

Comment: If your existing code works for the current week, can't you just omit the dateadd in the greaterthan/equals, to alter it to not have it start from the start of the week? (that is, replace `dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())` with just `CONVERT(date,getdate())` )

Comment: @gvee SET datefirst 1 gives an indication of monday being the first day of the week, but i agree it would be appropate to put in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))`
This means: add `1-datepart(dw, getdate())` days to current date.
This means `1-datepart(dw, getdate())`: go to starting date of current week.

But you need just current date `CONVERT(date,getdate())`.

Just change your code to:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 
SELECT distinct Initials
FROM Scheme
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, Dato, 105) >= CONVERT(date,getdate()) 
AND convert(datetime, Dato, 105) <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
AND RoomId = ? AND Initials IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks Giorgi :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit different, but more effective method:

```
SELECT distinct Initials
FROM Scheme
WHERE Dato >= cast(current_timestamp as date) -- currentdate
AND Dato <  dateadd(d, datediff(d, -7, current_timestamp)/7*7, 0)--end of week
AND RoomId = ? AND Initials IS NOT NULL
```

I assume Dato is defined as a date or datetime. Otherwise you may encounter some performance issues and this will not work.